# Convert Promise.all([list of promises]) to ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have written a function which returns a list of promises (code in ramda), and I then have to surround that with Promise.all() to resolve all promises and sends it back to promise chain.

For e.g.

```
// Returns Promise.all that contains list of promises. For each endpoint we get the data from a promised fn getData().
const getInfos = curry((endpoints) => Promise.all(
  pipe(
    map(getData())
  )(endpoints))
);

getEndpoints()   //Get the list of endpoints, Returns Promise
  .then(getInfos) //Get Info from all the endpoints
  .then(resp => console.log(JSON.stringify(resp))) //This will contain a list of responses from each endpoint
```

`promiseFn` is the function that returns a Promise.

How can I best convert this function into complete Ramda like, and use of either pipeP or something else? Can someone recommend?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what this does, maybe with more explicit variable names?  For instance, what does the outer `pipe` do?  It looks irrelevant.  What does `promiseFn` do?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have updated the question, please let me know in case you seek more information. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "*breaks the idea of using curried functions*"

Comment: @Bergi I want to make getInfo() completely using Ramda, as in resolving all the promises through ramda?

Comment: As one of the principals behind Ramda, I must suggest that making something completely by using Ramda should never be a goal unless it's an exercise to learn Ramda.  It's simply a tool to use where it helps.

Comment: @geek So you want to avoid using `const` declarations, initialisers, arrow functions, parameters, using `Promise.all`, function calls, using `getData`? Those all aren't part of Ramda.

Comment: What does `pipe(map(getData()))(endpoints)` do that `map(getData(), endpoints)` would not do?

Comment: Also is `getData` really a nullary function that returns a function that converts an endpoint into something?  It looks odd to have `map(something(/* no args here*))`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for the comments. Some of them really helped. But I really wanted to remove Promise.all and still be able to resolve the list of promises being returned by getData() and map.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, But I really want to remove Promise.all call and try to use anything that is available in Ramda for that?

Comment: @geek No, there is no equivalent of `Promise.all` in Ramda, exactly because it's already available as a builtin

Comment: @Bergi: That's not precisely the reason Ramda does not have an equivalent.  In fact we have pure-function equivalents for many native methods.  We deal very little with Promises because none of the authors much likes promises, preferring more lawful types such as Futures or Tasks.

Comment: In your pipe you can do `R.invoker(1, 'all')(R.__, Promise)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but I would rewrite it like that :

```
const getInfos = promise => promise.then(
  endpoints => Promise.all(
    map(getData(), endpoints)
  )
);

const log = promise => promise.then(forEach(
  resp => console.log(JSON.stringify(resp))
));

const doStuff = pipe(
  getEndpoints,
  getInfos,
  log
);

doStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean using [pointfree notation](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch05.html#pointfree).

I'd recommend using [`compose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose). It's a great tool when using `ramda`.

```
const getInfos = R.compose(
  Promise.all,
  R.map(getData),
);

// Now call it like this.
getInfos(endpoints)
  .then(() => console.log('Got info from all endpoints!'));

// Because `getInfos` returns a promise you can use it in your promise chain.
getEndpoints()
  .then(getInfos) // make all API calls
  .then(R.map(JSON.stringify)) // decode all responses
  .then(console.log) // log the resulting array
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```js
const getEndpoints = () =>
  Promise.resolve(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'])
const getEndpointData = (endpoint) =>
  Promise.resolve({ type: 'data', endpoint })

const logEndpointData = pipe(
  getEndpoints,
  then(map(getEndpointData)),
  then(ps => Promise.all(ps)),
  then(console.log)
)

logEndpointDatas()
```

I hesitate to combine just 2 functions with pipe / compose. Things like `then(map(callback))` reads fine once you get used to it. And I try not to take promises as parameters.